# In a Json.NET Merge, can individual changes be logged?

Tags: json, merge, json.net

Is there any way to identify the changes that have been made in a Merge? For example, here are two JSON files, `test1.json`

```
{
  f1: "String",
  f2: true,
  f3: 1000001,
  f4: [1]
}
```

.and `test2.json`

```
{
  f1: "String",
  f2: 1,
  f3: 1000002,
  f4: [1,2]
}
```

In the first, `f2` is a Boolean but in the second `f2` is a Number. Similarly, `f3`'s value changes and an extra item is added to `f4`.

Is there any way to record these changes? I am most interested in the change of data type rather than in the change of content.

Comment: Do you need to do it recursively, or just for the root object?

Comment: @dbc Recursively. Some of the structures are many layers deep. The goal is to have some statistical measure of whether certain properties are always of a specific type or whether occasionally they change type. With that data we can cook up a schema which we will use for a subsequent data migration.

Answer (score 1):

You could read in both JSON files, deserialize them both to [`Dictionary<string,object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2), then compare them with [`String.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) and output the differences.

The below demo assumes the one level deep JSON structure as shown in the question. The same logic should apply for deeply nested JSON objects, but how you traverse the JSON objects and match keys will change. For deeper layered JSON objects with different depths, recursive traversal will need to be used.

**Basic Demo:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace MergeJson {
    public static class Program {
        private static string FILE_ONE = "test1.json";
        private static string FILE_TWO = "test2.json";

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts JSON file into Dictionary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path of the JSON file</param>
        /// <returns>The converted Dictionary</returns>
        private static Dictionary<string, object> GetJsonDict (string path) {

            // Read json file into string
            string json = File.ReadAllText (path);

            // Deserialize JSON string into dictionary
            var jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>> (json);

            return jsonDict;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args) {

            // Get both Dictionaries
            var jsonDictOne = GetJsonDict (FILE_ONE);
            var jsonDictTwo = GetJsonDict (FILE_TWO);

            // Go through each key in the first dictionary and compare with second dictionary
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in jsonDictOne) {

                // Get key and value
                var value = entry.Value;
                var key = entry.Key;

                // Ensure second dictionary has key
                if (jsonDictTwo.ContainsKey (key)) {
                    var otherValue = jsonDictTwo[key];

                    // Compare both values and output differences
                    if (!value.Equals (otherValue)) {
                        FormattableString difference = $"Difference in key {entry.Key}: {value} -> {otherValue}";
                        Console.WriteLine (difference);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Difference in key f2: True -> 1
Difference in key f3: 1000001 -> 1000002
Difference in key f4: [
  1
] -> [
  1,
  2
]
```